# Modify the @HtmlValidationMessageFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

The default behaviour of the ValidationMessageFor seems to render out a simple span.

Is it possible to produce something like

```
<span class="error required">
  <p><span>Required field</span>
    <a class="close" href="javascript:closeError();"></a>
  </p>
  </span>
```

I want to render out a nice looking message box and cant do it with just the single span.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom helper to personalize this:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MyValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> ex)
    {
        var result = htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(ex);
        var res = string.Format("<span class=\"error required\"><p>{0}<a class=\"close\" href=\"javascript:closeError();\"></a></p></span>", result.ToHtmlString());
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(res);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.MyValidationMessageFor(x => x.Foo)
```